# How to map LTO sections to output sections in GCC (Arm) linker?

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, object-files, lto

I have a linker file that I use as input for Gnu Arm Embedded Toolchain.

It contains, among other things, an output section like this:

```
.text :
{
  . = ALIGN(4);
  *(.text*)
  *(.rodata*)
} > FLASH
```

, where FLASH is a MEMORY block.

My issue is that, when I compile a C++ file with LTO (link-time optimization), some of my code is put in non-".text" sections in the resulting object files. These sections seems to be consistently named:

```
.gnu.lto<SOMETHING>
```

As a result, they are not placed in my .text output section.

How can I map LTO input sections to my .text output section?

Comment: `some of my code is put in non-".text" sections in the resulting object files` And? Looks like they belong there. What is the reasoning for why do you want not to put them there? Is this XY question? It sounds like you have a bug in your code, that bug is manifesting only with LTO, and you are trying to fix something unrelated. Most probably, as usuall, your interrupt vectors get optimized out.

Comment: It's not a problem as such that the code exists in non-".text" sections but I lack the knowledge of how to include this in my output .text section resulting from the linking. I'm in control of the interrupt vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my issue was related to a misunderstanding in how the VMA and LMA statements work in GNU linker files. So, in essense the LTO section are mapped correctly. Thanks to anyone who spent time on this.